# Why did my avatar change?

Tags: discussion, support, profile-picture, gravatar

My network-wide gravatar identicon used to be a pleasant blue, now it's bright green. I didn't change my email. Did Stack Exchange change its email hashing algorithm or something?

Comment: It seems there is something going on with your account. There is activity visible on multiple sites, yet your SO profile doesn't show it? Did you have multiple accounts by any chance? Did they get merged?

Comment: @Bart Not as far as I'm aware. I do have several of my network accounts set to "hidden", though.

Comment: Okay, because your SO account seems to show only SO, while on Meta here I see some posts on other sites in your profile. And when going to those sites, I see a more extensive network account.

Comment: @Bart just to keep track of issues that seem related, at least in appearance, [this was reported yesterday on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283659/cannot-access-the-per-site-metas-of-only-a-few-se-sites#comment919395_283659) although  an account merge was involved there.

Comment: @rene It's actually a cross-site dupe of my [MSE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283643/323179). I've done a bit of research if you look at my question. Also note that I see the right icon, since it depends on where your IP address is.

Comment: Seems that it might be a general phenomenon. If I go to edit profile page I can see to different avatars, one on the toolbar and one editable in the profile settings. I think Laurel cross-site dupe, gives a lot of insights.

Comment: Related MSE question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283643/why-is-my-profile-image-different

Comment: Happened to me too. Has anyone reported this bug to gravatar?

Comment: I am having the same problem. On a related note, what hashing algorithm does SO use? I've tried both MD5 and SHA1 on my email address and username and neither produce the hash that my gravatar uses.

Comment: See: http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1218/hmm-something-funny-with-the-what-do-they-call-it-gravatar/1219#1219

Comment: Actually, [the comma splice here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/332880/4) is grammatically incorrect. The two parts of this sentence (before and after the comma) are actually complete phrases, and independent clauses cannot be separated by a comma alone. You need either a coordinating conjunction (*e.g.*, and, but, for, so, yet, nor), or a semicolon that serves the same role. So this *is* an issue of grammar, but I'm electing to leave a pedantic comment instead of re-editing the post because you are entitled to a certain degree of personal expressive freedom. :-)

Comment: @barron Stick your stackoverflow profile URL in to archive.org. Check out an old version of your profile, right click the avatar and save locally. Then upload to SO.

Comment: Sorry for the "me too", but "me too!". My actual picture disappeared and the gravatar is different than what I had before my actual picture. Weird.

Comment: This happened to me now.... ?!?!

Comment: As of 2023, gravitar icons do differ from the previous versions. I did not check the exact dates, but icons did change between 2019 and 2022 (based on a quick check I did on my own profile).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It seems a gravatar problem, not related to Stack Overflow.

Your big avatar (https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/efef01b733b5e8af2d8670efe6990e90?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG) is bright green:

[image]

Your small avatar (https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/efef01b733b5e8af2d8670efe6990e90?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG) is more bluish:

[image]

Note the hashes are identical, so it's not a change in the email hashing algorithm.

Comment: Both your URLs show the bluish avatar. Looks like the URL with a `r=PG` parameter returns the bluish avatar and without the parameter, the bright green one. Size doesn't matter.

Comment: @gre_gor Size matters, [128px](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/efef01b733b5e8af2d8670efe6990e90?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG) is bright green.

Comment: Photoshop will fix that right up for you.

Comment: The only blue one seems to be of 32 px size, perhaps one could blame caching (in this case, commonly accessed sizes having longer life spans).

Comment: My avatar changed too and it looks completely different, but the weird part is that only one of my 2 computers. On one of them it still shows as usual.

Comment: my avatar also changed from rose to blue

Comment: I tried reporting this issue to gravatar but their contact form seems closed. Someone from SO should communicate this issue to gravatar people IMHO.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: And it's gone! Looks like the cache for the smaller one has been purged now as well.

Comment: Mine was a green one like the one posted and it was that way across all StackExchange networks until today; now it's a yellow one on StackOverflow and completely different dark green one on SuperUser .. I say StackExchange and/or gravatar need to embrace this issue and just have any default profile pics be random across the board and for each login .. makes the Q&A more colorful

Comment: Also happened with me. My old gravatar was yellow-brown. My new one is light blue.

Comment: @CainNuke: This is because of caching. I pressed Ctrl + F5 in my Firefox and my avatar changed to different on 2nd computer as well.

Comment: Aaarghh!!! My avatar just changed too

Comment: Yeah my avatar just changed too ?!

Comment: And mine! It's horror.

Comment: And gravatar's fix replaced all avatars. They're both green now :D

Answer (score 38):

**No.  Stack Exchange did not change its email hashing algorithm or something.**

In the mean time, thought I would post this as a workaround until Gravatar stops having a meltdown.

Copy your Stackoverflow profile URL in to archive.org. Check out an old version of your profile, right click the avatar and save locally. It should be a nice high res version. Then upload to SO.

Comment: Thanks. This saved [me](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333506/3785314) today.

Comment: Does not address the question.

Comment: @barron Hold on, let me edit my answer to address the very clear question you asked.

Comment: That was actually a **really** good answer. It worked for me. Never occurred to me that you could look up a historic version and grab the image.

Comment: Thanks!  This has really bothered me.  After finding your answer, I actually searched to see why I couldn't award you a bounty.  (Can't on meta - baa).

Comment: my avatar changed recently for some reasons and your post helped me fix it.

Answer (score 5):

As others already pointed out, the problem is caused by Gravatar not Stack Overflow.

As a workaround I used google to search for my profile image with the query `stackoverflow my_username`.

Luckily Google caches (most) images on the results page.

Comment: Does not address the question.

Comment: Well the other answers already address the question. This answer is meant for anyone who wants a workaround to fix the problem.

Comment: I tried this before making my [post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333506/3785314) but it did not work. You have to be careful because there are many many images from Gravatar that look alike. If you really look closely, you will realize that they are not the-same. Some are brighter images, some are darker.  Google search result returned very similar images but I compared them to my old one(low quality) and they were **similar** but not the-same. The best way to do this is to simply use archive. You will find your original image.

Answer (score 2):

My gravatar as displayed by SO has also changed recently, though I have neither altered my SO or gravatar profiles.

I notice that SO is selecting the `PG`-[rated](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/) version of my avatar, per the `r` parameter at the end of the url:

```
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f057f53afd6fffc5075d8d59277cd103?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG
```

Unsurprisingly this URL as-is yields the anonymous geometric design.

I need to go dig up the relevant login so I can't yet confirm, but I recall marking my avatar as rated `G`.  If I change the parameter to `G` then I get my G-rated face:

[image: My smiling face]

*I also get my face if instead I merely down-case `PG` to `pg`.*

So it seems either SO has added, changed or even just up-cased this GET parameter recently, or gravatar has introduced a fǝature where requests for rating `PG` are no longer equivalent to those for `pg`.

Particularly, they break case-insensitivity in their claim:

> To allow images rated G or PG use something like this:
>
> https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50?r=pg

Comment: Same problem here, changing to lowercase pg fixes it. Shouldn't be this a separate bug report?

Comment: Hmm apparently it seems to be a caching problem on gravatar's side; changing my gravatar to rating X, and then after a while back to G fixed the issue. Probably the uppercase/lowercase thing just forced the lowercase one to be generated (bypassing the broken cache).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that this does not just affect Identicons but also uploaded Avatars hosted by Gravatar.

while fixed now (at least for me), for the most part of yesterday my size 48 avatar image was returning a 502 - Bad Gateway (and this was on 2 different computers on 2 different networks, work and home)

[image: my avatar]

however another user's gravatar image at size 32 was giving a 502 - Bad Gateway while mine wasn't

[image: Face Sealing Jutsu on Madara Uchia!]

so yeh if you like your avatar not to be buggy like this and you don't want to wait for Gravatar to get their crap together (seriously duplicate Meta questions keep coming up about the identicons, how is it not fixed yet?) your best bet is to go to **Edit Profile & Settings** >> **Edit Profile**, click on the avatar and upload it to https://i.stack.imgur.com (since if that goes down so does mostly every image in the questions/answers)

#### Downloading your Avatar

if you've used a non-identicon avatar and didn't delete the original image just upload it. otherwise go to the Gravatar url where your avatar is coming from (generally right click and open image or inspect the HTML and get the URL from that) and alter the `s=` argument to get your desired size. hopefully you don't get a 502 for the size you want.

the largest size used on Stack Exchange, to my knowledge is 328 which is used in the Profile Page (this is resized down to 164 but the url is pointing to 328)

Comment: There is a problem with the images uploaded to http://i.stack.imgur.com as well. I uploaded my avatar today (first time that I'm using a custom non-identicon avatar) the way you mentioned and it's different [here (328)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESoqk.jpg?s=328) and [here (48)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESoqk.jpg?s=48) - looks like a misbehaving downsizing algorithm to me