# Profile picture changed automatically

Tags: bug, profile-picture

My profile picture changed 5 minutes after answering a question. I did not change it myself.

It used to look like this:

[image]

Now, it looks like this:

[image]

Why did this happen? Is this an update or something? How can I revert back to the old default profile picture?

Again I did not change this. This happened after answering a question and refreshing the page.

**EDIT**:

Found something weird. The picture on the top bar is **still** my old picture:

[image]

But the ones that appear when I ask or answer question is totally different:

[image]

**and**

[image]

I guess this is a bug...

**EDIT 2**:

Only wanted to revert back to the old picture which I had no copy of.

I was able to do this with superphonic's help.

Go to  [archive.org](http://archive.org), then post in your profile url. Something like below:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/3785314/programmer

[image]

Choose a timeline of your profile when it was good then right click on your Profile picture and select **Open image in a new tab**. You will get the hi-res version of your old profile picture. Right click on that image and click **Save image as**.... You can then re-upload that image.

[image]

Comment: I've seen several posts in the recent weeks, that complained about the same bug. Seems that the gravatar engine is the culprit.

Comment: Ok, but is there a fix? How can revert back to the old one? @animuson The duplicated answer does not have a solution on how to revert back to the old image...Any solution?

Comment: If you happen to have a high-res backup of the old one, you can upload it. Otherwise there's nothing we can do. We have zero control over this issue - it's all on their side.

Comment: I did not upload this picture here. It was the default picture automatically assigned to my profile by SO  when I signed up. Since this is the case, there is no way to get it back?

Comment: Mine did this randomly today as well; to boot, it's a different picture on the different sites, so a yellow gravatar on SO and a dark green one on SU, yet my old one was a default green one similar to yours posted across all SE networks.....I thought my account got hacked somehow at first until I saw the different avatars on the different network sites ... bug indeed ..

Comment: @txtechhelp I am glad there is another person that experienced this. I first thought I was hacked then waited to see if anything else would change in my account. Nothing changed so I think it is a bug.

Comment: @Programmer Stick your stackoverflow profile URL in to archive.org. Check out an old version of your profile, right click the avatar and save locally. Then upload to SO.

Comment: @superphonic I just did and it worked. I was able to get the hi-ress profile picture. This should the actual answer but the question is closed. The linked answer does not even solve the problem. Thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: @Programmer No worries.