# My Avatar has completely changed

Tags: bug, accounts, gravatar

**This is a NOT a duplicate of [Why did my avatar change?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332880/why-did-my-avatar-change) That question is about a colour change, and it seems to be fixed.**

Today (31st August 2016) my avatar on Stackoverflow completely changed. Since I created my account almost 4 years ago it has been this:

[image]

But today it is this:

[image]

Nothing has changed on my end, no email change, no signing in differently. In fact, SO was still open in my browser from yesterday and all I did was refresh the browser and the new avatar appeared?

What's happened and how do I get my old avatar back?

Comment: @vaultah I state right at the top of this question that this is not a duplicate of that question

Comment: I can see why you might be upset, the first avatar is awesome!

Comment: @superphonic _But there is no resolution on that question_ It's exactly what's said in the dupes answer. Gravatar is not under control of the SE engine. They can't provide a solution for the problem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ incorrect. It's a different problem, which may or may not have the same resolution as the other issue. The bottom line is, it is emphatically **NOT** the exact duplicate of an existing question.

Comment: @Conrad You probably misunderstood what I said. Stack Engine doesn't have control over Gravatar and such it's pretty useless to ask about Gravatar problems here. That's also clearly stated in the duplicate question. As usual it's the answer that counts, not the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did my avatar change?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332880/why-did-my-avatar-change)

Comment: Yea, this _is_ a duplicate. It's the same issue. Something's going on on Gravatar's end, and there's nothing SO can do about it.

Comment: Google "gravatar email hash cracked" to find basic reasons to be happy about it.

Comment: @Cerbrus You say it's the same issue, but the duplicate you point to only mentions a colour change, which for all you know is NOT the same issue as my complete identicon change. Secondly the duplicate flag description says `This question has been asked before and already has an answer` Yet my question is **definitely** not the same as the duplicate you mention, its a completely different problem, it "may" have the same cause, but you don't know that, and the **question** is not the same therefore not a duplicate question. I am not trying to argue for the sake of it, just seems incorrect to me.

Comment: The point of the duplicate is that it's the ___same problem___: Gravatar is having issues which cause the images to change. The answer is the same: there's nothing SO can do, the issue is at gravatar's end. Sure, the two issues aren't literally identical, but they're similar enoughto warrant closure.

Comment: @superphonic the duplicate text is kinda misleading like that (think it was prposed to have it changed, not sure). just like questions on the main site like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39359090/1028804) if it's fully answered *in any answer* of the linked duplicate then it's a duplicate, if not it's up to the asker of the question to explain why the answers in the duplicate does not solve their issue.

Comment: My avatar just get changed (the other way round, if you know what I mean): from more detailed image to the current more abstract one. Will this problem be solved automatically by gravatar? Have you changed it back by yourself. I don't have my old avatar.....

Comment: @bolu See my answer on this question. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333531/1743833 - It explains how to get a copy of your old avatar to upload it manually. Gravatar will hopefully sort the issue at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always change the image back, yourself.

In your case, visit:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/1743833

You can change your avatar, there.

> [image]
>   [image]

Just upload your old gravatar image there.