# Avatar displayed instead of profile picture

Tags: support, profile-picture

There seems to be a strange behavior in my profile.

Maybe someon can explain this to me.

When writing posts the gravatar is displayed:

[image: Image normal state]

When i hover the picture the profile picture is displayed:

[image: Image hover state]

How can i display my profile picture on all posts?

I tried to update my profile but that didn't help.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: I see your profile picture. Have you tried Ctrl-F5 (or clearing your cache)?

Comment: Yes i did. But that didn't help.

Comment: I've the same behavior here, your post image (red) link is `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4c81c03b798280d08d59858a3e5d7c6b?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG` And the hover image is `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4c81c03b798280d08d59858a3e5d7c6b?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG`. Only the size is changing, did you change your picture recently ? sounds like a cache problem on gravatar's side.

Comment: There was an issue a while back with gravatar, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285174/gravatar-profile-image-not-showing-sometimes and on MSO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332880/why-did-my-avatar-change/334006#334006

Comment: FWIW, I'm seeing your identicon here.

Comment: Try to update your avatar in Gravatar, maybe using a smaller JPG image (512x512).

Comment: Updated my Gravatar. Now it seems to work. Thanks to all you guys givig me useful tips! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

:)

Comment: I'm assuming a cache problem at Gravatars side.