# Why is my profile picture near the search bar different from the one on my profile?

Tags: bug, profile-picture

The profile picture that is displayed near the search bar on stackoverflow is different from the one displayed on my SO profile. Why is this?

Near the search bar:

[image]

On my profile:
[image]

Is this a bug?
This question is different from [Why did my avatar change?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332880/why-did-my-avatar-change) because for that asker, the avatar changed everywhere. My avatar is different in two places where it should be the same.

Comment: Did you try clearing your cache? (For what it's worth: I'm seeing the profile one)

Comment: Oh dear, is Gravatar serving different images for different dimensions again?

Comment: I can't reproduce; try a force-reload. It could be you still have a cached copy of a previous avatar (can happen when you change your email address).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Or maybe it was still cached from that bug ;-)

Comment: @Stijn: No-repro. It's not that bug.

Comment: @Cerbrus cleared my cache and the profile one is now also displayed near the search  bar! Thank you!

Comment: I'll add that as an answer, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the past, Gravatar had [an issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332880/why-did-my-avatar-change) where it was serving different images for different sizes.

However, that issue has been resolved, and doesn't seem to have resurfaced.

Another reason you could be served different images is if you recently changed your email address.
Clearing your cache should fix the image.

Comment: Thank you! I did change my email address quite some time ago and only recently noticed the different profile pics, which is why I couldn't see the connection. After clearing my cache, the pic from my profile is now also the one displayed near the search bar.