# Gravatar identicons appearing...sometimes

Tags: support, gravatar

When my avatar appears on posts, I'm seeing the identicon

[image: identicon]

but when I hover over the signature I get my avatar back:

[image: avatar]

Comment: Gravatar does this every now and again. I've usually fixed it by reuploading the image

Comment: I haven't noticed this happening. Is it only on your own posts or are you also seeing this with other user's gravatars? Also, have you recently changed your image?

Comment: It's Gravatar's fault, nothing SE can do about it. Just upload the image locally

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a known problem with Gravatar. Reuploading your avatar can fix it, but lately I've also had success with a Ctrl-F5 (same effect as clearing the browser cache).

The avatar displayed in the expanded user card is loaded from a different URL, one with `?s=64&...` instead of `?s=32&...`. The issue seems to affect different sizes independently, I haven't had it occur for all sizes at the same time.

You can also drop Gravatar and upload your avatar to Stack Overflow's imgur space, by going to https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current, clicking on *Change picture* and clicking the *Upload a new picture* button.

Comment: Related: [Why did my avatar change?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332880/why-did-my-avatar-change). Gravatar.com doesn't want us to have nice things, apparently.