# My avatar icon has reset, but only on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, gravatar, avatar

Just now when I went to Stack Overflow I noticed that my avatar icon has changed. But only the little one at the top of the page, next to my reputation. When I open my profile, or even my Network Profile, all shows up fine.

On further inspection, the URLs for the icon seem different. On SO it's:

https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e760113e81ab0e7a7f1f41ab6774b47d?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1

[image: Wrong image]

While the rest of the network it's:

https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7bd2e50770e937761cfc3811a332bccc?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG

[image: Correct image]

I'm not sure why this is happening, I have not changed anything in my profile for ages. I'm guessing it's a bug with some sort of cache somewhere.

Comment: Gravatar is a source of weird behavior by itself and due to long obsolete implementation details on the SE side, for example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352705. If you want full control over your profile image, grab it from the gravatar one that is correct and then upload it manually in your profile then sync your profile and gone is gravatar ...

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332880/why-did-my-avatar-change

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar

Comment: @rene If this was on Gravatar's side, sure. But the URLs are generated by the Stackexchange network, no?

Comment: Yes, based on an email field no-one has access to anymore. So once something gets ungenerated you're out of luck. I'm pretty sure this won't get fixed.

Comment: Wait, I just noticed that you said there's an option to manually upload the pic to SE. Great, I'll do that!

Comment: Yeah. It is unfortunate. Gravatar was a nice idea but the service and the implementation needs to be stable / reliable / predictable. None of those criteria apply.

Comment: A couple of notes... First, there's a log for your profile mods can see that shows when you change profile pics. The last entry for you was Apr 12 '18. Second, I went into your profile and it shows the Gravatar is selected. So... that's weird

Comment: I noticed the same today too. However I could change it back under edit profile

Comment: The image appears to exist in your profile. Have you tried switching to the Identicon, saving it, and then switching back to the current Gravatar (and saving)?

Comment: @Makyen - I have no particular attachment to Gravatar, so if I can upload the picture here and save it, all the better. But before I did that, I also saw the section which said "Gravatar/Identicon/Custom picture" and "Gravatar" was selected there, with the proper picture. Identicon was the same as in the thumbnail, but it was NOT selected. Once more I think this has something to do with some cache between the main source of truth and the webpage. Anyways, problem solved now, hopefully permanently. :)

Comment: It doesn't look like a Gravatar issue if it's isolated to SO site and nowhere else, not even meta.SO. I also see the same in profile section as mentioned by Vilx.

Comment: @Cas - No, SO meta also had the issue. But not other sites like Physics or CodeGolf.

Comment: @Makyen, I have the same issue. On SO only (and NOT on metaSO) hash vave changed from `cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b` to `885acc481ceee39aae2d52ce18208e57`. Doesn't seem like gravatar issue.

Comment: Same as @Qwertiy. My Main SO avatar is the default, but Meta SO and other sites like Ask Ubuntu are fine.

Comment: The [Community♦ User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) is affected too?

Comment: Is there some place we should go to for user advisories about stuff like this, please? I too have suffered, and if this was a known problem a little more proactivity would have helped.

Comment: Now meta icon is updated too...

Comment: there are two wolves inside you, one is a gravatar

Comment: @TamásSengel - Dammit, I better see a doctor. The WHO recommended amount of wolves inside of an adult human is 0.

Comment: @Vilx-, maybe they are not _bad_.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[Way back in the day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194094/267572) we started salting Gravatar image URLs, but only for new users. Older users do *not* have a salted Gravatar URL.

Today we performed a backfill so we can drop an old column `Users.Email` which contains an email address only used for this purpose but we didn't take into account that users created prior to August 2013 would not have salted URLs.

It's gonna take a little while to unwind the backfill and fix everything correctly - for now you can use [the solution posted by Joe Phillips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409143/my-avatar-icon-has-reset-but-only-on-stack-overflow/409160#409160), but it should be dealt with by tomorrow morning.

Apologies for the inconvenience.

**UPDATE 1** A fix has been approved but I'm not particularly keen on running another backfill network-wide on a Friday afternoon. It'll be run to address the issue with all affected users profile images on Monday morning (UTC).

**UPDATE 2** I've run the backfill across Stack Overflow and Meta SE and all looks well. Running across the rest of the network now.

**UPDATE 3** Annnnnd we're done. Apologies for the inconvenience folks

Comment: I'm taking this advice with a grain of ... never mind ;)

Comment: Right, we have seen what can come out of hasty decisions on a Friday afternoon...

Comment: Why did this happened to me who clearly created their account after 2013 if that's the cause?

Comment: @valisstillwithMonica upon further investigation we found that the problem went a little deeper than accounts before August 2013. Either way they’ll be fixed tomorrow

Comment: Seems fixed now.

Comment: Interesting. Around the time you posted your update 3, my avatar here on MSO changed. On SO and MSE it's still the correct one.

Comment: @honk looks like an oddity with metas - they'll rectify themselves after a daily reconciliation process runs later today.

Comment: @DeanWard It's still different for me on Meta than it is on the main site.

Answer (score 14):

If you go to the "Edit your profile" page, you can click on "Change picture" and re-select the Gravatar one and this seems to fix the issue. I don't have an explanation for why it happened though.

[image: Gravatar selected but not displaying]

Comment: Side note: Gravatar was already selected for me but it wasn't the one being displayed

Comment: When updating, there is the risk of choosing *"Save and copy changes* ***to all*** *public communities"* instead of *"Save changes for* ***just this*** *community"*... It may or may not be possible to recover by going to the corresponding meta site (before it syncs up/before it is too late). It is better to use the opportunity to ***back up*** the profiles, especially the free-form profile text (before pressing anything).

Comment: Perhaps add a disclaimer?